# Fourier sine series expansion

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-series, partial-derivative

> The function $f(x)$ is defined as $$f(x)=1\qquad0<x<\pi$$
>
> Sketch the odd extension and show that the Fourier sine series expansion is
>
> $$f(x)~\frac4\pi\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin((2n-1)x)}{2n-1}$$

In this question, $f(x)=1$, $a_0$ is obviously $2$ and $a_m$ and $b_m$ are zero when plugged into Fourier series equation. Could you please explain why the Fourier series can be expanded in such this form?

Comment: It's the odd extension, so you should further define $f(x) = -1$ when $-\pi < x < 0$, and $f(x) = f(x+2 \pi)$.

Comment: And what is the meaning of the $\sim$ in the problem?

Comment: Thanks Ron. It seems to me that Fourier series is used to approximate a curve in a specific format. As we are approximating the real equation, that's why we use "~".

Comment: Meaning of $\sim$ ... I guess it means show that the function $f$ has that Fourier series, but you do not have to show that the Fourier series converges to $f(x)$.

Comment: @GEdgar: My read on Fourier Series is that, because the convergence is not pointwise, the equality resulting from taking the limit as the number of terms increases has particular meaning.  That all said, it is still an equality.  The $\sim$ sign, which in the absence of context implies an asymptotic relation (and is not an equivalence relation in a strict sense) is thus a notation misuse as I see it.

Comment: I think the $\sim$ notation may be widely used in the context of Fourier series.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you got $a_0 = 2$ and $A_n, B_n = 0$ so I'll post the solution.

You have

$$\begin{align}
f(x) &= 1 \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} B_n \sin\bigg(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\bigg) \ \ \text{(because we're doing the odd extension)} \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} B_n \sin(nx) \ \ \text{(with $L = \pi$)} \\
\end{align}$$

Integrating over our domain and using orthogonality, we find

$$\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\pi} f(x)\sin(mx)dx &= \int_{0}^{\pi} \sin(mx)dx \ \ (1)\\
&= \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} B_n \int_{o}^{\pi} \sin(nx)\sin(mx) dx \\
&= \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{B_n}{2} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \sin(nx)\sin(mx) dx \ \ \text{(as an odd function $\times$ odd function is an even function)} \\
&= \frac{B_m \pi}{2},\ \ n = m \ \ (2)
\end{align} $$

Equating $(1)$ and $(2)$, we find

$$\begin{align}
\frac{B_m \pi}{2} &= \int_{0}^{\pi} \sin(mx)dx \\
\implies B_m &= \frac{2}{\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi} \sin(mx)dx \\
&= \frac{2}{\pi} \bigg[\frac{-\cos(mx)}{m} \bigg]_{0}^{\pi} \\
&= \frac{-2}{m \pi}\bigg[(-1)^{m} - 1 \bigg] \\
&= \begin{cases} 
      0 & m = \text{even} \\
      \frac{4}{m \pi} & m = \text{odd} \\ 
\end{cases}
\end{align}$$

Hence we should set $m = 2j - 1$ for $j \ge 1$ to keep only those cases that are non-zero.

Hence, our solution is given by

$$\begin{align}
f(x) &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} B_n \sin(nx) \\
&= \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} B_m \sin(mx) \ \ \text{(using $(2)$)} \\
&= \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{4}{m \pi} \sin(mx) \\
&= \frac{4}{\pi} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(mx)}{m} \\
&= \frac{4}{\pi} \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin((2j - 1)x)}{2j - 1} \\
\end{align}$$

**EDIT**

$$\begin{align}
f(x) &= 1 \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} B_n \sin(nx) \\
\end{align}$$

Multiply both sides by $\sin(mx)$ for orthogonality

$$\begin{align}
\implies f(x)\sin(mx) &= \sin(mx) \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} B_n \sin(nx) \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} B_n \sin(nx)\sin(mx) \\
\end{align}$$

where we can take the $\sin(mx)$ term inside the series because we aren't summing over $m$ so it can be thought of almost like a constant.

Integrate both sides over $[0, \pi]$

$$\begin{align}
\implies \int_{0}^{\pi} f(x)\sin(mx) dx &= \int_{0}^{\pi} \bigg( \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} B_n \sin(nx)\sin(mx) \bigg) dx \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} B_n \int_{0}^{\pi} \sin(nx)\sin(mx) dx \\
\end{align}$$

Replace $f(x)$ with $1$

$$\begin{align}
\implies \int_{0}^{\pi} f(x)\sin(mx) dx &= \int_{0}^{\pi} \sin(mx) dx \\ &= \int_{0}^{\pi} \bigg( \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} B_n \sin(nx)\sin(mx) \bigg) dx \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} B_n \int_{0}^{\pi} \sin(nx)\sin(mx) dx \\
\end{align}$$

Comment: accepting an answer does not close the question; it removes the question from the unanswered list.  (An upvote does that too.). The OP has the right to accept a new solution that is posted after (s)he accepts yours.

Comment: Thanks. But can you please explain why we need to put the partial sum when integrating over the domain with orthogonal property?

Comment: Also, when integrating over the domain, do we need to multiply by one over pi as well? I thought the one over pi was a part of the formula.

Comment: @RonGordon Sure, but that is why I stated _if you are happy with the solution_.

Comment: @Tommy_Smith I didn't use the formula for the Fourier coefficients, I _derived_ the formula for $B_m$ instead. I think it provides a more comprehensive overview of what we're actually trying to do.

Comment: How do you sketch an odd extension? @Mattos

Comment: @Hen The odd extension is just a straight line at height $f(x) = 1$, from $0 \le x \le \pi$, then a straight line at height $f(x) = -1$ from $\pi \le x \le 2\pi$ etc.

Comment: but if asked to sketch the odd extension of f(x)=1 from 0≤x≤π, then would be solely draw the straight line form 0≤x≤π. @Mattos

Comment: @Mattos thank you so much. Aside from this question, do you suggest any website/free programme that can plot a complex partial sum of N terms of a series? I tried to google that but none of them seems good to me.

Comment: @Mattos after rereading few times of your solution, I still dont get how you go from equation(1) to the next line. Can you please further explain that step to me please.

Comment: @Hen I don't know what you are talking about? The odd extension means to extend the function periodically in a particular fashion, the fashion which I explained. See [here](http://www.mth.msu.edu/~gnagy/teaching/11-winter/mth235/lslides/L37-235.pdf).

Comment: @Tommy_Smith You can graph it on Mathematica, see [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2537/plotting-partial-sums-of-fourier-series) or google 'Mathematica plot Fourier Series'. Also, I'll make an edit to my original post for equation $(1)$.

Comment: @Tommy_Smith have you tried desmos?